# Alternative proof verification: If $2n+1$ and $3n+1$ are perfect squares, $40$ divides $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, congruences

This is an alternative proof of the aforementioned fact.

Let $2n+1=p^2$ and $3n+1=q^2$. Then, 
$$ n=q^2-p^2 \tag{1}
$$ and 
$$
3p^2-2q^2=1\, . \tag{2}$$ 
Modulo $5$, $(2)$ reduces to 
$$
3(p^2+q^2) \equiv 1 \pmod{5}\qquad\hbox{or}\qquad p^2+q^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}\, ,$$ 
which is possible if and only if $p^2 \equiv q^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Modulo $8$, $(2)$ reduces to $2(q^2-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$, which implies that $q$ is odd, and hence $p^2 \equiv q^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$. Thus, $p^2-q^2$ is divisible by both $5$ and $8$, and hence also by $40$.

The proof looks right to me, but I'd like to check. Please help.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I don't follow how you got the reduction mod 8 from 2 for some reason.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I believe the fact that $p^2=2n+1$ implies that $p$ is odd, so $p^2\equiv 1\bmod 8$ is implied here.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut okay, but that wasn't using 2 above, nor was it related to $2(q^2-1)\equiv 0 \pmod 8$,  at least not until you reduce $3p^2$ to 3  giving: $$-2q^2\equiv -2 \pmod 8\implies -2q^2+2\equiv 0\pmod 8\implies 2q^2-2\equiv 0 \pmod 8\\\implies 2(q^2-1)\equiv 0 \pmod 8$$ 

still a big leap for me to follow.

Comment: I am agree with @Carl Schildkraut; your proof is correct.

Comment: I also think the proof is correct, but you could make your life easier at one point: Instead of considering your equation (2), you could just add the two equalities $2n+1 = p^2$ and $3n+1 = q^2$ to get $5n+2 = p^2+q^2$, which is precisely what you get with slightly more effort.

Comment: Thanks to everybody on this forum for their help and advice.